# General Question about Sylow subgroups (ruling out possibilities by group actions)

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

So I was going over my abstract algebra notes and found a Sylow subgroup problem to show that $A_5$ is the only simple group of order 60, i.e. if $G$ is a simple group of order 60, then $G \cong A_5$.

I understand almost everything I have written down, but toward the end we get to the point where $\vert Syl_3(G)\vert = n_3 = 1,4,10$. And since $G$ is simple, we rule out 1 (which I understand), but then I have written: "Suppose $n_3 = 4$, then $G$ acts on $Syl_3(G)$ by conjugation, so done."

I'm not understanding where this comes from or why we get a contradiction. Could someone explain this please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The conjugation action induces a homomorphism $G\to S_4$ with transitive
(and so non-trivial image). This must have a non-trivial kernel.